# NPM gives this error while updating every package locally, but it allows to update package globally

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, material-ui

[image]

While updating packages **locally** to their latest version, npm gives this error.
But it allows to update them globally, why?
and How should solve this ERESOLVE error to update them locally?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try to downgrade node.js to 14 (are you using 16+?)

using nvm https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md

Comment: yes its 16.15.1

Comment: well try to downgrade it i had similar issue with old project